# Easiest way to get first x characters?

Tags: powershell

`Out-String` doesn't seem to work, at least for versions 5.1 and 6b2:

```
"$('a'*10) $('b'*10)" | Out-String -Width 10
```

Result:

```
aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`.Substring()` Method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx). This fails if the substring location is not contained in the string. (In this case, if the string is shorter than 10 characters)

```
"$('a'*10) $('b'*10)".Substring(0,10)
```

Alternatively, you could use `-replace` to remove the last part of the string. Since nothing will match when the string is shorter than 10, it will not replace anything but will not fail and will just return the original string.

```
"$('a'*10) $('b'*10)" -replace '(^.{10})(.*$)','$1'
```

Comment: That fails when the string has less than 10 characters.

Comment: @mtman Noted in the answer, an alternative method is given that returns the original string rather than fail when the string is shorter than 10 characters.

Comment: Good idea, I think the regex should be `^(.{10}).*$` to ensure it cannot pick characters from the middle.